# Can I generate a secondary ID that is used for identifying a row in API calls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating an API with Spring boot.

I want to have an ID that is private (*id*) to the DB as the primary key and a secondary id (*identifier*) that is used to access rows for modification or deletion and is displayed to the user.

However, this only creates a null identifier.

**Is there another way to do this or is this whole thing a bad idea and I should just generate the UUID as my primary key and live with exposing that?
**
Below is an example below of my model, I'm using jakarta persistance.

It successfully generates the id (as a sequential number), and the user name is managed as expected. It does create all 3 columns. But *identifier* is null.

I did notice in the jakarta docs that @GeneratedValue is only tested for primary keys, so maybe there's another annotation that would do the same for just a regular column?

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private String identifier;

  private String name;

  public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Long getId() {return id;}

  public String getIdentifier() {return identifier;}

  public String getName() {return name;}

  protected User() {}
}
```

And repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Having a private `long` id and a public `uuid` identifier is perfectly fine. Perhaps declaring the field as `UUID` instead of `String` will help? Or you need a different way to generate it. If all else fails, just set one yourself using `UUID.randomUUID()`.

Comment: Thanks @Jorn I'd gotten so caught up in Jakarta not working with it to generate my UUID, it had gotten completely away from me and I hadn't even thought of other ways to generate it. GeneratedValue still failed, but initializing it with UUID.randomUUID() does what I needed!